# Can't mount DRBD device to directory

Tags: linux-device-driver, drbd

I installed drbd for replicate data on two host. After installing successed, I check status drbd:

```
root@host3:~# cat /proc/drbd
version: 8.3.13 (api:88/proto:86-96)
GIT-hash: 83ca112086600faacab2f157bc5a9324f7bd7f77 build by root@sighted, 2012-10-09 12:47:51
 0: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Primary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:105400 nr:0 dw:0 dr:106396 al:0 bm:20 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:d oos:0
```

But when I try to: *mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt* (/dev/sdb1 - device drbd), It not working. This is error:

```
root@host3:~# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'drbd'
```

So, what can I do to mount drbd device?

Answer (score 0):

You're in Primary/Primary so I assume you want to format the DRBD device with a Filesystem that can be mounted/accessed by more than one system simultaneously like GFS2 or OCFS2. You'll need to do this before you can mount the device.

This type of configuration has a lot of requirements, and is probably too much to cover in a stack post. However, you should be able to follow the GFS2 primer in LINBIT's DRBD users guide here:
https://www.linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/users-guide-drbd-8-4/#s-gfs-primer